# Asynchronously populating a Java Map and returning it as a future

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, java-8, future, completable-future

I've got a map of objects which are expensive to create, and so I want to create the objects and fill the map in parallel with other processes in my application. Only when the main thread actually needs to access the map should the application wait for the asynchronous task(s) populating the map to finish. How can I most elegantly accomplish this?

### Current approach

Currently, I am able to create each individual object in the map itself asynchronously using [`CompletableFuture.runAsync(Runnable, Executor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync-java.lang.Runnable-java.util.concurrent.Executor-) analogously to in the example code below, but I'm unsure of how I can build a `Future`/`CompletableFuture`-type mechanism for returning the `Map` itself when ready:

```
public static class AsynchronousMapPopulator {

    private final Executor backgroundJobExecutor;

    public AsynchronousMapPopulator(final Executor backgroundJobExecutor) {
        this.backgroundJobExecutor = backgroundJobExecutor;
    }

    public ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> apply(final Map<String,Integer> input) {
        final ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> result = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(input.size());
        final Stream.Builder<CompletableFuture<Void>> incrementingJobs = Stream.builder();
        for (final Entry<String, Integer> entry : input.entrySet()) {
            final String className = entry.getKey();
            final Integer oldValue = entry.getValue();
            final CompletableFuture<Void> incrementingJob = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                result.put(className, oldValue + 1);
            }, backgroundJobExecutor);
            incrementingJobs.add(incrementingJob);
        }
        // TODO: This blocks until the training is done; Instead, return a
        // future to the caller somehow
        CompletableFuture.allOf(incrementingJobs.build().toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new)).join();
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, with the code above, when code calls `AsynchronousTest.create(Map<String,Integer)`, it already blocks until the method returns the entirely-populated `ConcurrentMap<String,Integer>`; How can I turn this into something like a `Future<Map<String,Integer>>` so that I can use it at a later time?:

```
Executor someExecutor = ForkJoinPool.commonPool();
Future<Map<String,Integer>> futureClassModels = new AsynchronousMapPopulator(someExecutor).apply(wordClassObservations);
...
// Do lots of other stuff
...
Map<String,Integer> completedModels = futureClassModels.get();
```

Comment: I may have read things wrong here, but in case I did not -  shouldn't you just submit this task of computing the expensive Map to a pool and return a `Future` from that?

Comment: Each individual map value is very expensive to compute, so I need that to be paralllelized as well.

Comment: If you don’t want to wait for the result, don’t call `.join()`…

Comment: @Holger that doesn't give me the map.

Comment: `return CompletableFuture.allOf(incrementingJobs.build().toArray( CompletableFuture[]::new)).thenApply(x -> result);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Holger states in his comment, you must avoid calling `.join()` and rely upon `thenApply()` instead, e.g. like this:

```
public static class AsynchronousMapPopulator {

    private final Executor backgroundJobExecutor;

    public AsynchronousMapPopulator(final Executor backgroundJobExecutor) {
        this.backgroundJobExecutor = backgroundJobExecutor;
    }

    public Future<Map<String, Integer>> apply(final Map<String,Integer> input) {
        final ConcurrentMap<String, Integer> result = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(input.size());
        final Stream.Builder<CompletableFuture<Void>> incrementingJobs = Stream.builder();
        for (final Entry<String, Integer> entry : input.entrySet()) {
            final String className = entry.getKey();
            final Integer oldValue = entry.getValue();
            final CompletableFuture<Void> incrementingJob = CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
                result.put(className, oldValue + 1);
            }, backgroundJobExecutor);
            incrementingJobs.add(incrementingJob);
        }
        // using thenApply instead of join here:
        return CompletableFuture.allOf(
                incrementingJobs.build().toArray(
                    CompletableFuture[]::new
                )
            ).thenApply(x -> result);
    }
}
```